# Jekyll Not Displaying Layout for Static Page

Tags: ruby, yaml, jekyll, github-pages, static-pages

in root folder I have

designing_minimalist.md

```
---
title: Case Study: Designing Minimalist Interfaces For Teaching New Cognitive Tool Use
layout: default
---

# Case Study: Designing Minimalist Interfaces For Teaching New Cognitive Tool Use

Quantum Pilot is a SHMUP-puzzle about fighting clone ships that mirror how you attack them. (...)
```

default layout:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:black">
<body link="white">
<body vlink="white">
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<h1><a href="index.html">main</h1>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8" style="color:white">
        {{ content }}
    </div>
</div>
```

When I run jekyll build, I get `_site/designing_minimalist/index.html`

but my root/index.html file has the default layout:

```
<html>
<body style="background-color:black">
<body link="white">
<body vlink="white">
<style>
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
</style>
<h1><a href="index.html">main</h1>
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span8" style="color:white">
        <p><a href="https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quantum-pilot/id935956154?mt=8">>Quantum Pilot: Clone enemies remember how you killed them and fight back mirroring your attack</a></p>

<p><a href="designing_minimalist/index.html">>Case Study: Designing Minimalist Interfaces For Teaching New Cognitive Tool Use</a></p>

    </div>
</div>
```

root/index.md

```
---
title: main.
layout: default
---

[>Quantum Pilot: Clone enemies remember how you killed them and fight back mirroring your attack](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quantum-pilot/id935956154?mt=8)

[>Case Study: Designing Minimalist Interfaces For Teaching New Cognitive Tool Use](designing_minimalist/index.html)
```

Why is the default layout not being applied to my static page?

Comment: What did you call static page ? Are you talking about _site/designing_minimalist/index.html ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one. for my static page.

Comment: So `_site/designing_minimalist/index.html` is generated, but it doesn’t have the layout? What does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colon in the title doesn't work. Removing the colon fixed the issue.